# How to refer to a listview subitem by its name,not by its index?

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have been wondering for a while about the code below:

```
ListView1.View = View.Details   
ListView1.Columns.Add("c1")   
ListView1.Columns.Add("c2")  
Dim Item As New ListViewItem    
Item.Text = "1"
Item.SubItems.Add("2")
ListView1.Items.Add(Item)
```

---

```
'MsgBox(ListView1.Items(0).SubItems("c1").Text) 'this is wrong  
MsgBox(ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(0).Text) 'this is right
```

I want a way to refer to the column by its name, because it is more readable, and lessens the chance of making a mistake. However, the program won't build. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why is your question tagged with C#? What does the code snippet you have shown has to do with this programming language?

Comment: i am sorry because i did not find vb.net category.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify name for `ListViewSubItem` and refer to subitem by that name:

```
Dim subItem As New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem
subItem.Name = "c1"
subItem.Text = "SubItem"
Item.SubItems.Add(subItem)
```

If you add your subitems in this way, `MsgBox(ListView1.Items(0).SubItems("c1").Text)` will work.

**Update:**

Unfortunately, this won't work for the first subitem. To fix this, you might need to create all subitems (including default) before `ListViewItem`:

```
Dim subItems As ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem() = New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem(2 - 1) {}
subItems(0) = New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem()
subItems(0).Name = ListView1.Columns(0).Text
subItems(0).Text = "Default SubItem"
subItems(1) = New ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem()
subItems(1).Name = ListView1.Columns(1).Text
subItems(1).Text = "SubItem 1"
Dim Item As New ListViewItem(subItems, 0)
ListView1.Items.Add(Item)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a little bit of LINQ:

```
Dim c1Items = From subItem In ListView1.Items(0).SubItems.Cast(Of ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem)()
               Where subItem.Name = "c1"
MsgBox(c1Items.First.Text)
```

[`Enumerable.Where`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803) filters a sequence of values based on a predicate. `First` takes the first element. So it takes the first subItem's `Text` with `Name = "c1"`.

**Edit**: 'm not so familiar with Winform controls. If the SubItem name is not set, you could use this LINQ query to find the index of the ColumnHeader with the given `Text`. Then you can use it to get the correct SubItem:

```
Dim c1ICol = (From col In ListView1.Columns.Cast(Of ColumnHeader)()
              Where col.Text = "c1").First
MsgBox(ListView1.Items(0).SubItems(c1ICol.Index).Text)
```

Comment: @user1518100: Edited my answer. I'm not so familiar with winform controls, so it may be true that i've overlooked a simple solution or this works not always. But try out yourself.